# Ubuntu Core serial port on Raspberry PI 2

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, serial-port

I am trying to package an applications which uses a serial port as a Snap. Target platform is Raspberry Pi 2 running Ubuntu Core 16.

From the documentation I gathered that I should add the 'serial-port' plug and then connect it, but that interface is not available on RPi. I am using an USB to serial adapter at /dev/ttyUSB0.

My application works in devmode, but on strict permission is denied.

This is my minimal snapcraft.yaml:

```
name: myapp
version: 0.0.1
architectures: [armhf]
summary: reads stuff
description: |
  writes stuff
grade: devel
confinement: devmode

apps:
  writer:
    command: bin/serialreader.wrapper
    plugs:
      - serial-port

parts:
  myappfiles:
    plugin: dump
    source: .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the `serial-port` slot is meant to be implemented by a gadget snap, by a device manufacturer. Serial ports cannot currently be accessed from strict confinement on Ubuntu Core without a gadget snap exposing them, and cannot be accessed from strict confinement on classic Ubuntu at all.

See [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1606674) as well as [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1645445) for more information. It's my hope that this situation changes soon. Until then, the only way to do this is to create your own gadget exposing the serial devices you need, create your own Ubuntu Core image containing it, and flash that image to the Raspberry Pi.

- The official Raspberry Pi 2 gadget can be found [here](https://github.com/snapcore/pi2-gadget). You can fork it and modify it as necessary.
- A tutorial for creating your own image [can be found here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/create-your-own-core-image).

Please do mark those bugs as affecting you if that's the case.

Comment: Thank you for quick explanation. I wasn't completely sure what gadgets even mean. I will fork the gadget and add the required slots.